# function call from JQuery Event handler

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. I have searched previous posts but couldn't find anything. I am trying to do call another function from Video Ended Event handler. its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // doing something
   $("#video1").bind("ended", NextFrag());
});

function NextFrag(){
   Window.alert("Hello World");
}
```

This is not working. I cannot see any alert printing "Hello World".

Basically I need to solve the above problem to do the following task. I want to play different fragments of video. The algorithm should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   NextFrag();
});

function NextFrag(){

   // IF First FRAGMENT do this
      $("#video1").html('<source src="FirstURLFromArray.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' );

    // ELSE DO THIS
      $("#video1").bind("ended", function(){
         $("#video1").html('<source src="NextURLFromArray.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' );
         NextFrag();    // call itself again.       
      });
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: `$( "#video1" ).bind( "ended", NextFrag );` Ditch the parens. You want to bind the function, not invoke it immediately.

Comment: The `window` is lowercase, won't work in camelcase.

Comment: Stupid me. You both are right. Many thanks. its working now.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("#video1").bind("ended", NextFrag);
```

This will pass the function as a callback, instead of evaluating it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the function will already have been evaluated at that point. A function invocation evaluates the function's body, but the function itself is evaluated when its function object is crated (in this case, when the function declaration is evaluated).

Comment: I just completed the task and posted the final code (oops!!!! I can't answer my own question for 8 hours - I will do it tomorrow). Many thanks for your help. I am not sure if you can help me get some points.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#video1").on("ended", function() {
    NextFrag();
   });
});

function NextFrag(){
   alert("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: I actually need to load first video before using the ended event handler. Many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I just completed the task. I did something like this and it is working.

```
var index = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
NextFrag();
});  

function NextFrag(){
if (index < url.length){
    if(index == 0 )
    {
        //The only difference for index=0 is that the player is not autoplay  
        $("#video1").html('<source src= " '+ url[index] + '" type="video/mp4"></source>' );
        index++;
        $("#video1").bind( "ended", NextFrag);

    }else
    {
         $("#VideoContainer").html('<video  id="video1" controls autoplay > "<source src= "'+ url[index]+ '" type="video/mp4"></source> </video>' );
         index++;
         $("#video1").bind( "ended", NextFrag);
    } 
}
}
```